# Weakening of the $T_1$ axiom

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is any set, one trivially has that every non-void subset $A$  can be completed by a proper subset $B$ to the whole of the space, i.e. $A\cup B=X$ (in this case the union can be taken disjoint, of course).
Now, if $X$ is a $T_1$ space, subspaces are just unions of closed subspaces (singletons).

I was thinking if this property can be considered in the non $T_1$ setting, i.e. considering those spaces for which each non-void union of closed subspaces can be completed to the whole space by a proper union of closed subspaces. Do these spaces have a name?

EDIT: So I'm interested in the class of spaces that satisfy: for each $A\ne \varnothing$ which is a union of closed subsets, there is a $B\ne X$ which is a union of closed subsets satisfying that $A\cup B=X$

Comment: Do you want the union $A\cup B=X$ to be disjoint as well?

Comment: No -- In fact, if you want the unions to be disjoint, it is easily shown that this property together with $T_0$ implies $T_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call a point $p \in (X, \tau)$, a topological space, a "dense point" iff $\overline{\{p\}} = X$, or equivalently, $p \in \bigcap\{O \in \tau\setminus\{\emptyset\}\}$. If $C$ is a proper (closed, if you like) subset of $X$ and $X$ has no dense points, we can write $$X= C \cup \bigcup_{x \notin C} \overline{\{x\}}$$ so we completed the union to $X$, in the OP's parlance by proper closed sets (because all these closures of singletons are that, by asssumption on having no dense points).

So among the spaces for which you can do this, are the spaces without dense points. Now think about when $X$ has a dense point and is not indiscrete: then we cannot do this "completion" all the time.

So the class is far wider than all $T_1$ spaces, probably too wide to be useful.

Comment: I wanted the whole union to be proper (not just each of the closed sets in the union), which is a significantly stronger condition. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @David what is a proper union of closed subsets? Please define.

Comment: The union is a proper subset of $X$.

Comment: @David so the condition is : for each proper closed subset $C$ of $X$ there is a proper closed subset $D$ of $X$ such that  $C \cup D \neq X$? Then take $C=D$.

Comment: No. I've just edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @David my characterisation still stands: all spaces with no dense points plus the indiscrete space (all points are dense), are the spaces satisfying the condition.

Comment: Why would  $\bigcup_{x\not\in C} \overline{\{x\}}$ be proper?